# Download a file which is generated through https call using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, web-administration

Currently I have this short piece of code. The URL `https://dosomething.do` generates a .csv file.  I can run the powershell code and in the shell I can see the content of the file. However the file itself is not downloaded. I would like to specify where to save it after a download. What are my options here?

```
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("hxxx", $securepassword)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dosomething.do" -Credential $credentials
```

Comment: Try pipe `Invoke-WebRequest` to `Out-File`

Comment: works like a charm,, thank you. feel free to add it as answer so I can accept it

Comment: Actually `Invoke-Webrequest` has a `-OutFile` parameter that you can use to specify the path and filename of where you want the file to be saved.

Comment: yes thats what I did, no pipe needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-OutFile` parameter of `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dosomething.do" -OutFile C:\some\path\to\yourfile.csv
```